# Calculating the dimension of $\{\alpha \in \mathcal{L}(V,W) \, : \, \alpha(X) \subseteq Y\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and $X\leq V$ and $Y \leq W.$

I need to show that 
$$\dim\{\alpha \in \mathcal{L}(V,W) \, : \, \alpha(X) \subseteq Y\}=\dim X \times \dim Y + \operatorname{codim}X \times \dim W.$$

$\color{red}{\text{Is what I write below a valid proof? Is there a better coordinate-free proof?}}$

*Proof(?).* Start by taking bases $\{x_1,\ldots,x_r\}$ and $\{y_1,\ldots,y_s\}$ for $X$ and $Y.$

Extend these to bases $\{x_1,\ldots,x_r,v_{r+1},\ldots,v_m\}$ and $\{y_1,\ldots,y_s,w_{s+1},\ldots,w_n\}$ for $V$ and $W.$

A linear map $\alpha:V \to W$ satisfies $\alpha(X)\subseteq Y$ if and only if its matrix with respect to these bases looks like
$$\begin{bmatrix} * & * \\
O & * \end{bmatrix}$$
where $O$ is the $(n-s)\times r$ zero matrix.

It follows that 
$$\dim\{\alpha \in \mathcal{L}(V,W) \, : \, \alpha(X) \subseteq Y\}=mn-(n-s)r=rs+(m-r)n$$
and this is what we wanted.